# Set display of section tags to flex or grid

Tags: reveal.js

With Reveal.js, I would like to use flexbox and/or grids to layout slides.  Unfortunately, it seems Reveal.js always overrides the `display` property of `section` tags with `block` as part of its slide show/hide logic.  Viz:

```html
<section class="mylayout">
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
</section>
```

```css
section.mylayout {
  display: flex;
}
```

Has no effect, because Reveal.js adds a `style="display: block"` attribute to the `section` tag.

Is there any way around this?  It works to put a nested `div` inside the `section` and have that be grid/flex, but it just feels clunky and gross to have an extra layer in there that adds no other value than a workaround.

Has anyone else found a different way to address it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to use flexbox in the initialization settings now. See [this update on the documentation.](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/pull/1325)